# Low-possible wave function values and macroscopic unusual events correlation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, probability

1. Macroscopic world, all of it’s events, things is a “display” of microscopic world, as a building is a display of breaks it is made of.
2. Literally, macroscopic world is just conventionality, there is only microscopic world, as well, as atoms are conventionality, because an atom it is just quarks and electrons around them (roughly).
3. Microscopic world sets up, influences on macroscopic world and not vice-versa.
4. According to statements above, can be true, that macroscopic things or events, that human-called as unusual or non trivial are display of fundamental particles wave functions collapses at values with minimum probability instead of high ones for some reason?

Can there be a correlation between what is called unusual in macroscopic terms, and wave function collapse value?

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you are saying. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @flippiefanus I rewrote my question

Comment: There is no such thing as wave function collapse. That's merely a very poor mental model without any real utility that one should avoid. If you want to understand quantum mechanics, then you will have to learn to think in terms of reversible and irreversible energy transfers between systems made up of quantum fields. It's a completely different way of thinking about the world, but rewarding as it allows us to explain all known phenomena related to radiation and matter.

Comment: @FlatterMann, by wave function collapse, I mean some real state that particle occupies during “measurement” or rather interaction from possible states that can be calculated from its wave function. As for other part of Your comment, I am studying, and just wanted to share some assumption that I came to my mind recently.

Comment: The word "particle" is probably the worst misnomer in all of physics. Quanta are amounts of energy, momentum, angular momentum and charges. Quanta only "exist" as system property changes as consequence of an irreversible process (emission or absorption). How can something that doesn't even exist in the free fields have a state? It can't and doesn't. The way we present the theory at the non-relativistic level is simply somewhat misleading (for historical purposes).

Comment: @FlatterMann, probably I can’t argue with You, but I try, because I think (again, probably due to low knowledges), that in question I ask Your argument does not matter. As I understand, You are referring to QFT, where any, even massive particle is considered as wave of corresponding field (i.e. electron = electron field, photon = em field), but however, isn’t this model still have uncertainty principle and describing quants by some probability distribution?

Comment: Nothing is considered a wave, either, neither in relativistic or non-relativistic theory. Object (particle) and wave properties are merely two emergent properties of many-quantum systems. A probability distribution is, by definition of the word "probability", the description of an ensemble. It is not a description of single quanta.

Comment: @FlatterMann Okay, You want say, that considering microscopic world as entities, called particles which “motion” can be described by wave function is wrong? I should not apply that model? I do not argue, with the fact that mass can be converted to energy, so number of particles of specific sort, can be varying with time.

Comment: There are no objects in the microscopic world. Energy conservation misleads some people to believe that energy behaves like immutable objects, but that is simply not the case if we look at all the properties of energy rather than just the conservation aspect.

Comment: @FlatterMann, I am currently understand things, as electron or even photon is something discrete like a point, but they do not move in sense we understand. Photon or electron movement if it can be called so is described by wave function, while it is still remains as something like a point, discrete. As I read, there was a debate between Schrödinger and Born where first one thought that wave function describes exact particles, i.e. they are like cloud, a wave, but Born position, was that particles are point, and as the result of debate, Schrödinger accepted that position.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146332/discussion-between-flattermann-and-stdugnd4ikbd).